# What are some commonly used Xcode User Scripts?

Tags: xcode, scripting

I am fairly new to Xcode.  I am in the Xcode Customization talk at 360idev being given by @Kendall Helmstetter Gelner.  He demoed some Xcode User Scripts.

Is this a common feature used by seasoned Xcode developers?  If so, what are some of the useful user scripts that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the UserScript I've been using for inserting properties - from a highlighted class instance variable line, it creates a property definition in the header file and also a @synthesize statement in the implementation file.

To configure, create a new shell script user script, and copy in the code below.  Note that I made this a community wiki, so anyone who has improvements to the script, feel free to edit.

Make sure that Input dropdowns are all set to "From Selection", and that Output dropdowns are all set to "Display in Alert" (since there will be no output, the script just edits the files):

```
  #! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

# Get the header file contents from Xcode user scripts
my $headerFileContents = <<'HEADERFILECONTENTS';
%%%{PBXAllText}%%%
HEADERFILECONTENTS

# Get the indices of the selection from Xcode user scripts
my $selectionStartIndex = %%%{PBXSelectionStart}%%%;
my $selectionEndIndex = %%%{PBXSelectionEnd}%%%;

# Get path of the header file
my $implementationFilePath = "%%%{PBXFilePath}%%%";
my $headerFilePath = $implementationFilePath;

# Look for an implemenation file with a ".m" or ".mm" extension
$implementationFilePath =~ s/\.[hm]*$/.m/;
if (!(-e $implementationFilePath))
{
    $implementationFilePath =~ s/.m$/.mm/;
}

# Handle subroutine to trime whitespace off both ends of a string
sub trim
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;
    return $string;
}


# Get the selection out of the header file
my $selectedText =  substr $headerFileContents, $selectionStartIndex, ($selectionEndIndex - $selectionStartIndex);

#my $otherText = substr $headerFileContents, $selectionStartIndex;
#my $pulledText = "";
#if ( length($otherText) && $otherText =~ /.*$(^.*;).*/ )
#{
#    $pulledText = $1;
#}
#
#
#print $pulledText;


$selectedText = trim $selectedText;


my $type = "";
my $asterisk = "";
my $name = "";
my $behavior = "";
my $iboutlet = "";

# Test that the selection is:
#  At series of identifiers (the type name and access specifiers)
#  Possibly an asterisk
#  Another identifier (the variable name)
#  A semi-colon
if (length($selectedText) && ($selectedText =~ /([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\s*)+([\s\*]+)([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*)/))
{
    $type = $1;
    $type = trim $type;
    $asterisk = $2;
    $asterisk = trim $asterisk;
    $name = $3;
    $behavior = "";
    if (defined($asterisk) && length($asterisk) == 1)
    {
        $behavior = "(nonatomic, retain) ";
    }
    else
    {
        $behavior = "(nonatomic) ";
        $asterisk = "";
    }
}
else
{
    print "Bailing, error in Regex";
    exit 1;
}

# special case, see if we need to keep around an IBOUTLET declaration.
if ( length($selectedText) && ($selectedText =~ /IBOutlet/) )
{
   $iboutlet = "IBOutlet ";
}

# Find the closing brace (end of the class variables section)
my $remainderOfHeader = substr $headerFileContents, $selectionEndIndex;
my $indexAfterClosingBrace = $selectionEndIndex + index($remainderOfHeader, "\n}\n") + 3;
if ($indexAfterClosingBrace == -1)
{
    exit 1;
}

# Determine if we need to add a newline in front of the property declaration
my $leadingNewline = "\n";
if (substr($headerFileContents, $indexAfterClosingBrace, 1) eq "\n")
{
    $indexAfterClosingBrace += 1;
    $leadingNewline = "";
}

# Determine if we need to add a newline after the property declaration
my $trailingNewline = "\n";
if (substr($headerFileContents, $indexAfterClosingBrace, 9) eq "\@property")
{
    $trailingNewline = "";
}

# Create and insert the proper declaration
my $propertyDeclaration = $leadingNewline . "\@property " . $behavior . $iboutlet . $type . " " . $asterisk . $name . ";\n" . $trailingNewline; 
substr($headerFileContents, $indexAfterClosingBrace, 0) = $propertyDeclaration;

my $replaceFileContentsScript = <<'REPLACEFILESCRIPT';
on run argv
    set fileAlias to POSIX file (item 1 of argv)
    set newDocText to (item 2 of argv)
    tell application "Xcode"
        set doc to open fileAlias
        set text of doc to newDocText
    end tell
end run
REPLACEFILESCRIPT

# Use Applescript to replace the contents of the header file
# (I could have used the "Output" of the Xcode user script instead)
system 'osascript', '-e', $replaceFileContentsScript, $headerFilePath, $headerFileContents;

# Stop now if the implementation file can't be found
if (!(-e $implementationFilePath))
{
    exit 1;
}

my $getFileContentsScript = <<'GETFILESCRIPT';
on run argv
    set fileAlias to POSIX file (item 1 of argv)
    tell application "Xcode"
        set doc to open fileAlias
        set docText to text of doc
    end tell
    return docText
end run
GETFILESCRIPT

# Get the contents of the implmentation file
open(SCRIPTFILE, '-|') || exec 'osascript', '-e', $getFileContentsScript, $implementationFilePath;
my $implementationFileContents = do {local $/; <SCRIPTFILE>};
close(SCRIPTFILE);

# Look for the class implementation statement
if (length($implementationFileContents) && ($implementationFileContents =~ /(\@implementation [_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\n)/))
{
    my $matchString = $1;
    my $indexAfterMatch = index($implementationFileContents, $matchString) + length($matchString);

    # Determine if we want a newline before the synthesize statement
    $leadingNewline = "\n";
    if (substr($implementationFileContents, $indexAfterMatch, 1) eq "\n")
    {
        $indexAfterMatch += 1;
        $leadingNewline = "";
    }

    # Determine if we want a newline after the synthesize statement
    $trailingNewline = "\n";
    if (substr($implementationFileContents, $indexAfterMatch, 11) eq "\@synthesize")
    {
        $trailingNewline = "";
    }

    # Create and insert the synthesize statement 
    my $synthesizeStatement = $leadingNewline . "\@synthesize " . $name . ";\n" . $trailingNewline;
    substr($implementationFileContents, $indexAfterMatch, 0) = $synthesizeStatement;

    # Use Applescript to replace the contents of the implementation file in Xcode
    system 'osascript', '-e', $replaceFileContentsScript, $implementationFilePath, $implementationFileContents;
}

exit 0;
```